# Is there a Linq method to tell that A is the subset of B?

Tags: c#, linq

Let's I have 2 arrays `string[] A = { "a", "b", "c" }` and `string[] B = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" }`.

Is there any method that can tell directly that A is a **subset** of B? Except will just remove distinct elements of B, but won't tell whether it's completely a subset of B.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 12):

you can do this,simply:

```
A.All(B.Contains);
```

And you may wanna check  the `Length` to make sure they are not the same size and `A` is a subset

```
bool isSubset = A.All(B.Contains) && A.Length < B.Length;
```

Comment: AFAIK, any set is a subset of itself.

Comment: @Mephy yes, the above check would only be needed for a *proper* subset.

Comment: This can be _very_ inefficient depending on the size of your sets.

Comment: @CoryNelson and least readable of posted answers imo.

Comment: @brz It's readable to me... I read it as, 'Does B Contain All of A'. In fact, all the words of that sentence are in his statement except 'Does' and 'of'. :)

Comment: I suppose for more efficiency, you could compare the lengths first. But they can be equal and still return true.

Comment: Another nagging: the `Length`-check is pointless since even a longer array can be a subset of a shorter if there are duplicates: `{"A", "A"}` is a subset of `{"A"}`.

Answer (score 9):

There's even a method for this purpose. You could use [`HastSet<T>.IsSubsetOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358446(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var aSet = new HashSet<string>(A);
bool isASubsetOfB = aSet.IsSubsetOf(B);
```

Comment: This is not LINQ though. But perhaps it is more efficient than using linq.

Comment: @DeCaf: why using LINQ if there's already a readable and efficient method available?

Comment: No reason other than that the question asked if there was a Linq method.

Comment: @DeCaf: i guess OP just thought that there's nothing buil-in. I also like LINQ very much because it can increase readability but sometimes available methods are even more readable and more efficient. Basically LINQ are also just methods sitting in a class in the `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: This will likely be very slightly more efficient than mine. `Except` just builds a hash set behind the scenes.

Comment: @CoryNelson: you're right. I thought that yours doesn't need to load the `HashSet` completely but it also creates a `HashSet` from the second sequence(as opposed to mine which uses the first). http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-17-except/

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
bool isSubSet = !A.Except(B).Any();
```

Comment: Should probably negate it for readability, no? A ⊆ B is false for the example given when using this code, and that seems confusing.

Comment: In that case, make it an extension method like `IsSubsetOf()`.

Comment: Yes, you have to add `!` otherwise your checking if it's **not** a subset so not what it's suppoed to do.

Comment: @CoryNelson Maybe, but my point is that the variables are backwards. This code is checking something along the lines of "Is A a superset of B"

Comment: Ahah, now I see what you mean. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine SequenceEquals and Intersect:

```
var isASubsetOfB = B.Intersect(A).SequenceEqual(A)
```

Comment: Make sure you actually care about order when using this.